# How to find real address behind html link?

Tags: html

I want to analyze mango.com website. I am interested in the following link.
http://shop.mango.com/US/m/mango/clothing/dresses/day/?m=dresses32&v=Day
I find a viewall link on this page which can display all the items. 
http://shop.mango.com/US/all/mango/clothing/#firstitem

It seems the viewall link is the same for other categories. 
How to find the real address behind this viewall link?

Answer (score 0):

http://shop.mango.com/US/all/mango/clothing/#firstitem

http://shop.mango.com/US/all/mango/clothing/ is the link.

`#firstitem` is the id in the page.

Actually it's all in a whole html page, but if you want to display only a part of the page. Just change the css of id `display:none` to hide other parts.

Comment: I want to scrape all the item links from http://shop.mango.com/US/m/mango/clothing/dresses/day/?m=dresses32&v=Day. I am trying to use viewall link on the page http://shop.mango.com/US/all/mango/clothing/#firstitem . Clearly it is not working. The view all link is not the one I want.

Comment: what do you mean viewall link?

Comment: You can display all the items on one page. Search "View all" on this page http://shop.mango.com/US/m/mango/clothing/dresses/day/?m=dresses32&v=Day

Comment: Oh, actually, I really got your point now. It's dynamic...so i think it's hard to get.